# Cloudflare vs. Domain Hoster: A Records for both?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I don't understand how this works. I have a domain registered at domainhoster X and a VPS at hoster Y. Since a week I am using the follwing DNS settings at my domainhoster X:

- A RECORD (pointing to my server IP)
- NAMESERVERS from my domain hoster

Now I registered on Cloudflare and added my domain. They told me to delete the domainhosters name servers and use their instead. Okay.

But: Do I have to delete the A RECORDS on at my domainhoster X, too and use only the A records entries on cloudflare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the NAMESERVERS of your domain to Cloudflare, your domain will follows the A RECORD rules on Cloudflare.

So you can but you don't have to delete the A RECORDS on your domainhoster X.
Only the A RECORDS changes on your Cloudflare DNS settings will have effect.